# Exporting sheet as new workbook but deleting buttons first works but also generates an error

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro that is tied to a button to export an excel sheet to a new workbook and save it. The macro deletes all the buttons before it saves. The macro works, the sheet is generated and saved, but before it closes I get an error and I can't figure out why!

```
Sub Export_IssuesLog()

Dim answer As Integer
Dim PathName As String

answer = MsgBox("Do you want to export the issues log?" _
& Chr(13) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Note: This macro automatically overwites versions with the same Revision Number. Please ensure the revision number is updated correctly.", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

  If answer = vbYes Then
  
        PathName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("Proj_no").Value & "_" & Range("Client_short").Value & "_" & Range("Facility_short").Value & "_IssuesLog_REV-" & Range("B4").Value & ".xlsx"
        
        ActiveSheet.Copy
        
        For Each btn In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If btn.AutoShapeType = msoShapeStyleMixed Then btn.Delete
        Next
        
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathName
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
  Else
    Exit Sub
    
  End If

End Sub
```

If I remove this piece of code, which does successfully delete the buttons, the macro works perfectly.

```
        For Each btn In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If btn.AutoShapeType = msoShapeStyleMixed Then btn.Delete
        Next
```

If I do include that bit of code the error it gives me is on the ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs line. It gives me a Run-time error '1004' - Method 'SaveAs' of object '_workbook' failed.

The thing is, it does actually save the workbook! I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 2):

### Referencing Objects

- Use `Option Explicit`.
- Try referencing all objects one at a time i.e. use variables.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportIssuesLog()

    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Make sure the workbook is active, or the ranges will fail.
    If Not swb Is ActiveWorkbook Then swb.Activate
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim dPath As String: dPath = swb.Path & "\" & Range("Proj_no").Value _
        & "_" & Range("Client_short").Value & "_" _
        & Range("Facility_short").Value & "_IssuesLog_REV-" & Range("B4").Value
    
    Dim Answer As Long
    Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to export the issues log?" _
        & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Note: This macro automatically " _
        & "overwites versions with the same Revision Number. " _
        & "Please ensure the revision number is updated correctly.", _
        vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    If Answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub ' canceled
    
    sws.Copy
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(1)
        
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In dws.Shapes
        If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeStyleMixed Then shp.Delete
    Next shp
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without conpfirmation
        dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dPath
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    MsgBox "Issues Log exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that's above and beyond, thanks so much! It works perfectly. My VBA knowledge is not nearly as advanced as yours. Are you able to explain what was going wrong with my code? I want to better understand how yours fixed the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, I cannot pinpoint what is the reason behind the error. This could be an example of why not rely on what is `active`. If you go line by line, everything looks fine except for the corrected issues. It looks like VBA got somehow confused about what is active but I'm sure it didn't. This kind of error is puzzling to me. Try reverting the code to your version a piece at a time, maybe you'll figure it out. And most definitely share if you do.

Comment: Here is a possibility but it's a stretch. `ActiveSheet.Copy` creates a new workbook. You continue using `ActiveSheet` as if you know that the new workbook is the active one, similar to referencing the new workbook with `Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook`, while you should reference it with `Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)`. To conclude, you are actually still in the source workbook and the code fails when you try to save it because the source file is an `.xlsm` file and cannot be saved as an `.xlsx` file without setting the correct file extension and `FileFormat` parameter.

Comment: That makes sense. What's curious is that it does actually save the file. Regardless, I'll be more careful about using "Active" in future.